# updated NVIDIA drivers: black screen or login loop

Tags: nvidia, updates, login, screen

I've recently changed my Nvidia driver version & rebooted to

1. [login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)
2. Black screen or [TTY](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66195/what-is-a-tty-and-how-do-i-access-a-tty)

This is not a exact duplicate of [Graphics issues after/while installing Ubuntu 16.04/16.10 with NVIDIA graphics](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760934/graphics-issues-after-while-installing-ubuntu-16-04-16-10-with-nvidia-graphics) because

1. not installing nvidia drivers for the first time
2. I have not installed or upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04: this question isn't specific to 16.04

Some of the answers are the same but the question is not an exact duplicate.

The justification for this post is the "inaccessibility" of the "duplicate" post to new users like in these examples:

- [13.10 Saucy login issues; black screen, loop, and freeze](https://askubuntu.com/questions/365686/13-10-saucy-login-issues-black-screen-loop-and-freeze)
- [Unable to solve login loop problem after installing Nvidia driver via run file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/850193/unable-to-solve-login-loop-problem-after-installing-nvidia-driver-via-run-file)
- [Changing Nvidia Driver black screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/664155/changing-nvidia-driver-black-screen)
- [Ubuntu 16.04 doesn't boot or gets stuck in login loop after install](https://askubuntu.com/questions/851245/ubuntu-16-04lts-doesnt-boot-or-gets-stuck-in-login-loop-after-install)
- [14.04 login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/746692/14-04-login-loop)

There are a lot of questions like these one. Just [search](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=updated+nvidia+login+loop+black+screen) for yourself, so let's make one good specific answer for the new guys.

Comment: About that... http://askubuntu.com/questions/760934/graphics-issues-after-while-installing-ubuntu-16-04-16-10-with-nvidia-graphics

Comment: @Vencen Why don't you improve the dupe target instead?

Comment: @ Zacharee1 thanks but no thanks. the title reads "Graphics issues after/while installing Ubuntu"  this is just for one specific thing to help new users with this problem

Comment: @Vencen read the answers. They address login loops and ending up in TTYs.

Comment: We have an excellent, well established Q&A addressing these nVIDIA issues thoroughly. You can see how helpful it has been to everyone from the upvotes. I see no need to create a new one

Comment: @Zanna however excellent it may be there are questions being ask like mine. just search "updated nvidia login loop black screen"

Comment: @Vencen but that problem is addressed in my Q&A. If you'd like, I can update the title, but the actual question and answers perfectly apply to what you are saying.

Comment: We don't need two masterposts for the same general problem.

Comment: @KazWolfe  the master post is inadequate. not in answers but in user friendliness . its to general for new people to understand that it contains there solution. it's hard for you tech geeks to  understand that new users need a more direct post.

Comment: @Vencen We're actually having a discussion (of sorts) in chat about how we can make that post (and answers within) more accessible.